# Complex ranges in R

Tags: r

Complex numbers are not ordered. Yet if I enter the following in R I get no error and a rather strange result:

```r
> 1+0i:2+4i
[1] 1+4i 2+4i 3+4i
```

Can you explain these results?

Comment: Did you mean `(1+0i):(2+4i)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` takes precedence over `+`, so what you've typed is equivalent to `1 + (0i:2) + 4i`, or `1 + c(0, 1, 2) + 4i`.

The `:` operator also tries to coerce things to numeric type; ordinarily you'd see a warning message, but it's not a problem when the imaginary term is `0` as it is in `0i`.